# How to automatically remove shadows from the image

Tags: photoshop, shadows

Is there a way using Photoshop CC 2017 to automatically even the colors (increase the brightness of the specific areas based on masked areas, or apply an average value to the whole image). I'm trying to prepare photos for texturing in ZBrush and currently, struggle to remove shadows on skin.

Comment: Would be a nice suggestion to Adobe. Never found an easy way.

Comment: It would be a lot better preparing a good light setup before taking the pictures.

Comment: @Rafael Agree, but I was talking about the photos that I already got and these were not made by me.

Answer (score 1):

If you select your target area [by any method, wand, lasso etc...] then add an Adjustment, the adjustment automatically uses only the selected area, including any feathering etc, & applies a mask. The mask can then be edited like any other.
You can also copy/paste other masks in, in a similar way to any regular layer.

quick example...
[massive overkill & hue/sat change just to show up easily]
You could substitute this for a subtle levels adjustment layer.

[image]

[image]